# Grails Export Plugin Doesnt Work with namedQuery

Tags: grails, groovy, export, grails-plugin

I am currently working on grails export plugin. The plugin works if I will just do simple list(). But if I associate it with namedquery, it doesn't work anymore. This is part of the code.:

```
def buildReport(){
  if(params?.format && params.format != "html"){ 
    response.contentType = ConfigurationHolder.config.grails.mime.types[params.format]
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.${params.extension}")

    exportService.export(params.format, response.outputStream,Building.selectStatus(params.q).list(params), [:], [:])
  }
}
```

The above code doesn't work. It throws this error :
Cannot invoke method getSuperclass() on null object. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Cannot invoke method getSuperclass() on null object

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Update:
I have this in my list.gsp:

```
    <g:form action="list" controller="building">
    <g:select id="user" name="q" from="${myapp.Construction.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${constructionId?.id}" class="many-to-one" />
    <g:submitButton name="Execute"/>
    </g:form>
```

If I submit that form, it will list or display the the building with the same construction Id. And somewhere down that code is:

```
    <export:formats
formats="['csv', 'excel', 'ods', 'pdf', 'rtf', 'xml']" action="buildReport"/>
```

That code will call the buildReport. But unfortunatedly the q or params.q of the select is null when calling the buildReport.

By the way, all this code is in one gsp file and it will display the same gsp when submitting the form.

---

Okay, I think I know why it doesn't works. Its because the params.q of

```
    Building.selectStatus(params.q)
```

is actually null! I don't know why its null. I have this in my list.gsp to pass the parameter:

```
    <g:textField name="q" value="${params.q ?: ''}" />
```

So what should be in the gsp to pass the params? Because here, I just found out that it is null.

By the way, before the buildReport is being called, the textfield has a value which the user will input.

Comment: is `selectStatus(params.q)list(params)` a copy-paste error?  (No `.` before `list`)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I accidentally deleted the dot. But it has in my code.

Comment: Using Building.list() just works fine. But not in Building.selectStatus(params.q).list(). Does anyone know why? and how can i make it work?

Comment: Does calling `Building.selectStatus(params.q).list()` work outside of the `exportService.export` call?

Comment: Yes it does, I tested it and it works fine.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Actually the Building.selectStatus(params.q).lis() doesnt work outside the exportService.export! I wonder why, because in def list() the query works. So what is better way to do it and make the export work?

Comment: I guess fix your named query, then the export will work as-is.  You don't say what your named query is (or your relevant domain objects), so other than that I doubt anyone can help...

Comment: Okay actually my namedquery is working. I tested it by manually putting it like this: Building.selectStatus('good').list(params). This one actually works! So the problem now is probably because the params.q is returning null.

Comment: The params.q in Building.selectStatus(params.q).list is probably null. So my question now is how to get the data from the search box somewhere in my gsp and pass it to that report block?

Comment: Rather than saying it's _"probably null"_, you should check and see what it actually is..  params can't be null, as you check it in the if statement.  What does params contain when `buildReport` is called?

Comment: So you're calling the `list` action in the form?  How does this call `buildReport`?

Comment: By clicking the export button? :)